# On what basis are certain elements selected for doping silicon?

Tags: metallurgy, conductivity

I read online that transistors are made by doping silicon with other elements such as arsenic, phosphorus, or aluminium in order to increase its conductivity. How are these doping materials selected?

Comment: This has an answer over on Physics (note it is my answer, so reader beware): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/132604/why-some-elements-of-same-group-cannot-be-used-for-doping-semiconductors/132625#132625

Comment: @JonCuster can we increase the conductivity of a conductor(like aluminium) by doping?

Comment: Typically 'doping' a metal results in increased scattering and a decrease in conductivity. Not an absolute rule, but pretty good bet for most metals.

Comment: @JonCuster what do you mean by 'increased scattering'??

Comment: The impurities are different than the lattice, interrupting the normal electronic structure, causing more carrier scattering.